# Audio Video merge using ffmpeg- moov atom not found error

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, video-editing

I am using below command for merging audio and video-

```
"-i", videoFileAbsolutePath, "-i", audioFileAbsolutePath, "-c:v", "copy", "-c:a", "aac", "-map", "0:v:0", "-map", "1:a:0", "-shortest", destinationFileAbsolutePath
```

For few videos I am getting below error-

> ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers\n 
>   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)\n  configuration: --target-os=linux
>   --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
>   --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot
>   --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include
>   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib
>   -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=\n  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103\n  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102\n  libavformat    57. 25.100 /
>   57. 25.100\n  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101\n  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100\n  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100\n  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101\n  libpostproc    54.  0.100 /
>   54.  0.100\nInput #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/keepvid/Amar_Akbar_Anthony_(HD)_-_Hindi_Full_Movie_-_Amitabh_Bachchan,_Vinod_Khanna,_Rishi_Kapoor,_1080P.mp4':\n
>   Metadata:\n    major_brand     : dash\n    minor_version   : 0\n
>   compatible_brands: iso6avc1mp41\n    creation_time   : 2018-10-23
>   19:02:47\n  Duration: 02:46:52.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1528
>   kb/s\n    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661),
>   yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 0 kb/s, 25 fps, 25
>   tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)\n    Metadata:\n      creation_time   :
>   2018-10-23 19:02:47\n      handler_name    :
>   VideoHandler\n[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xeb62d600] **Format
>   mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 detected only with low score of 1,
>   misdetection possible**!\n[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xeb62d600]
>   **moov atom not found\n/storage/emulated/0/keepvid/Amar_Akbar_Anthony_(HD)_-_Hindi_Full_Movie_-_Amitabh_Bachchan,_Vinod_Khanna,_Rishi_Kapoor,_1080P.m4a**:
>   **Invalid data found when processing input**

I got similar kind of error also while creating watermark-

```
"-i", videoFileAbsolutePath, "-i", imageFileAbsolutePath, "-filter_complex", "overlay=" + position, dest.getAbsolutePath()
```

> ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers\n  built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)\n  configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=\n  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103\n  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102\n  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100\n  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101\n  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100\n  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100\n  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101\n  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100\nInput #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp Business/Media/WhatsApp Business Video/VID-20190215-WA0016.mp4':\n  Metadata:\n    major_brand     : mp42\n    minor_version   : 1\n    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom\n    creation_time   : 2019-02-14 11:53:37\n  Duration: 00:00:45.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1444 kb/s\n    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 848x480, 1382 kb/s, 29.98 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)\n    Metadata:\n      creation_time   : 2019-02-14 11:53:37\n      handler_name    : Core Media Video\n    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 59 kb/s (default)\n    Metadata:\n      creation_time   : 2019-02-14 11:53:37\n      handler_name    : Core Media Audio\n[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xf0e30600] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!\n[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xf0e30600] **moov atom not found**\n/storage/emulated/0/Movies/IMG-20190225-WA0030.jpg.mp4: **Invalid data found when processing input**\n

How can i resolve this error?

Comment: How did you create these problem files? Provide a link to one so we can investigate further.

Comment: This looks strange in second log IMG-20190225-WA0030.jpg.mp4, problem with path?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the same output format as the input format and we assume that the video file does not contain any audio stream, you can adapt the following `FFmpeg` command to android :

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental output_merged.mp4
```

And if your one stream is longer than the other, you can add the `-shortest` option so that `FFmpeg` will stop encoding once one file ends.

Comment: Why did you include `-strict experimental`? It's not needed for AAC encoding unless your ffmpeg is ancient.

Comment: I didn't know that. I think we can find it within the [official FFmpeg documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#Codec-Options). Thanks BTW.

Comment: @SenDjasni your cmd is not working in many android 7 device like mi note 4. if you have solution please let me know. thanks